# Getting a unified $_GET array regardless of how you submit information

Tags: php, arrays, forms, get

So I am submitting this link into my php code:

For some reason I cannot even use example.com in the url below, but just add the directory to the script before.

```
https://www.example.com/test.php?info1234=3177%3B315961%3B317451%3B315511&info3598=121618%3B136803%3B13830%3B20532
```

**The above example.com url is 1 SINGULAR string. The user is ONLY submitted ONE thing. That one thing happens to be a php url which contains its own parameters.**

However, when I submit it using the the form, I get this `$_GET` array (This is my desired outcome **but the other way is fine too**):

```
Array
(
    [myurl] => https://www.example.com/test.php?info1234=3177;315961;317451;315511
    [info3598] => 121618;136803;13830;20532
)
```

---

And then if I submit it by putting the myurl into the actual url myself into my program's url myself. If I typed this url, and submitted it `localhost/test.php?myurl=https://www.example.com/test.php?info1234=3177%3B315961%3B317451%3B315511&info3598=121618%3B136803%3B13830%3B20532`, I get this `$_GET` array:

```
Array
(
    [myurl] => https://www.example.com/test.php?info1234=3177%3B315961%3B317451%3B315511&info3598=121618%3B136803%3B13830%3B20532
)
```

---

test.php

```
<?php
print_r($_GET);

?>

<form action="test.php" method="get">
  myurl: <input type="text" name="myurl"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Form submission - submits form data. You'll have to Add the extra parameter as a hidden input. ie:

```
<input type="hidden" id="info" name="info3595" value="entervaluehereinsuitalbleformat">
```

Comment: This just hides the input box, doesn't fix anything,

Comment: This answer is correct. If you want a `info3595` parameter you have to send it first. Here is an exemple of how to use a form with GET https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: @RomainB. It just hides the input box, I don't get how it fixes my problem. I want users to be ale to submit through both things. How can a use input the url example.com url into the input box? Also I don't know the information in the url, so I don't know the name of a key in the $_GET

Comment: since you're submitting your form via "get" you'll all parameters need to be specified in your form. Otherwise You can submit your form via "post", add the full url in  the form's action attribute.

Comment: `<?php
print_r($_GET);

?>

<form method="post">
  myurl: <input type="text" name="myurl"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>`

Comment: @Kalu Still doesn't work. I don't get 2 elements in my array. Also I would like the method to be get, not post

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
<form action="test.php" method="GET">

myurl: <input type="text" name="myurl"><br>

<input type="hidden" id="info" name="info1234" value="enter_value">
<input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

i hope it's useful