# How do I get a fully decoded string

Tags: php, forms, get, decode, urldecode

I am using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` instead of `$_GET` to get all my parameters. However, `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` encodes the string by itself. Thus, if a user sends an encoded string, it gets encoded again with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. Meaning I have to run `urldecode` twice.

Encoded string: `https://www.example.com/test.php?info1234=3177%3B315961%3B317451%3B315511&info3598=121618%3B136803%3B13830%3B20532`

If you use the link above to submit via the URL itself. Meaning you put the parameter in yourself, you get the string (which is what I want):

```
https://www.example.com/test.php?info1234=3177;315961;317451;315511&info3598=121618;136803;13830;20532
```

However, if you submit via form, you get a doubly encoded string. So when you decode, it only decodes once, and you have to run `urldecode` on it again to fully decode it:

```
https://www.example.com/test.php?info1234=3177%3B315961%3B317451%3B315511&info3598=121618%3B136803%3B13830%3B20532
```

How can I make sure I get the decoded string (I don't want to run `urldecode` twice on the string, as it makes my time complexity `O(2n)`. I want to try keep it at `O(1)` or at the very least `O(n)`. I know using `urldecode` means `n` every time.

```
<?php
$a = urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

$b = urldecode($a);
if(strpos($a, "%") != false) {
    echo "We had to decode twice<br>";
    echo $a . "<br><br>Then to:<br>" . $b;
} else {
    echo "Only decoded once!!<br>";
    echo $a;
}
?>

<form action="test.php" method="get">
  myurl: <input type="text" name="myurl"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

**Method 1:**

1. `localhost/test.php?https://www.example.com/test.php?info1234=3177%3B315961%3B317451%3B315511&info3598=121618%3B136803%3B13830%3B20532`
2. This decodes once

**Method 2:**

1. Go to `localhost/test.php`
2. Submit this link via the form
   `https://www.example.com/test.php?info1234=3177%3B315961%3B317451%3B315511&info3598=121618%3B136803%3B13830%3B20532`
3. This decodes twice

You will see you get 2 different outputs

Comment: "I am using $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] instead of $_GET to get all my parameters." Why?

Comment: If you are that concerned about time complexity(?) then don't start doing extra things you probably don't need to... it's all been done for you already and you are doubling up on code...

Comment: @ceejayoz because when I use `$_GET` I get 2 different types of datas. When I submit via form, I get 2 elements in the `$_GET` array (using the example.com link above). If I submit the the data in the url itself, I get an array with 1 element in the `$_GET` array.

Comment: @MatthewPage what do you mean? I need to decode, so I can split it up into an array within an array using `preg_split` with `;` and `&`. Then I can use a foreach loop to make it an associate array (so I can put all the info as an index, and all of its numbers, seperated `;` as an array of numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. I ran a test. If I pass in urlencoded value from a browser $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] has the urlencoded value. If I pass in non urlencoded value from a browser $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] has non urlencoded value.

Comment: @JasonK Updated my post (at the end, I show the methods)

Comment: @jasonK I wanted to use `$_GET`, but no one could answer my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438589

Comment: @Mikie They answered your questions. Your form just needs multiple `<input>` fields for your multiple parameters.

Comment: @ceejayoz But they aren't multiple input fields. Its just 1 string. Why am I getting 2 elements with `$_GET`. The `myurl` the user submits is a singular string. The user is submitted a url, and that url, could be a php url, and that php url that user submits may contain parameters (but it should be read as a string). Thus, I have to use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. Edited my other question (made the edits bold). The user is submitted 1 thing, a url, which happens to be a php url, and that url happens to contain its own parameters

Comment: You're being highly confusing here. If the user submits a form with a single field, `myurl`, that's what'll be in `$_GET`, as `$_GET['myurl']`. If you want to get parameters out of **that** submitted URL, you will have to parse it, likely with a combination of `parse_url` (to get its query string) and `parse_str` (on that parsed query string).

Comment: @ceejayoz sorry about that but $_GET['myurl'] will have the URL if the information is submitted in the url (not from the form). if it is submitted by the form, it automatically splits all the attributes.

Comment: That's simply not true. If you put `https://www.example.com/test.php?info1234=3177;315961;317451;315511&info3598=121618;136803;13830;20532` into the `<input name="myurl">` and submit it, you'll get a `$_GET['myurl']` with the value `https://www.example.com/test.php?info1234=3177;315961;317451;315511&info3598=121618;136803;13830;20532`. I just tested it. My test code: https://gist.github.com/ceejayoz/16cb2756a0c965ee808f7383caac2bf7

Comment: And here's a screenshot of the results: https://imgur.com/IWVhEG6